# Ubuntu 14.04 on XPS13 does not recognise projector: could not set the configuration for CRTC 64

Tags: projector

I am trying to get my XPS13 to hook up to the projector in the classsroom, but the moment I plug in the cable (using mini-display port to VGA adapter), the resolution on my screen dropped and nothing is shown on the projector. And I also get the following message: "could not set the configuration for CRTC 64". The resolution on my laptop would not change back to normal even after I unplugged the cable from my laptop.

The adapter is working fine as it would recognise an external monitor in my office without problem. The projector is fine too, I have tested it on other machines (with VGA port), one running the latest Linux Mint and another running Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit.

My current system runs Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What resolutions does the projector support?